# DBF update each column using xBaseJ

Tags: java, dbf

I need to update values of DBF, in a column and need to update each record of that column:

```
DBF classDB=new DBF("Test.dbf");
    double id;

    CharField  cval = (CharField) classDB.getField("A");  
    NumField  xval = (NumField) classDB.getField("B");
    NumField  yval = (NumField) classDB.getField("C");
    classDB.read();


    id = Double.parseDouble(xval.get())+Double.parseDouble(yval.get());
    cval.put(Double.toString(id));
    classDB.update();
    System.out.println("Updated");
```

I am getting updated my first value on the column, how can update the entire column? I need something like this

```
while(..next()){

id = Double.parseDouble(xval.get())+Double.parseDouble(yval.get());
        cval.put(Double.toString(id));
        classDB.update();
        System.out.println("Updated");  
}
```

I am using xBaseJ API to do this.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
final XBaseFile dbf = new XBase().open(new File("..."));
try {
  for (int i = 0; i < dbf.rowCount(); i++) {
    if (dbf.go(i) && !dbf.isDeleted()) {
      final Double x = dbf.getValue("B");
      final Double y = dbf.getValue("C");

      dbf.setValue("C", String.valueOf(x + y));
    }
  }
} finally {
  dbf.closeQuietly();
}
```

I am using [xbase4j](http://github.com/Yasas/xbase4j) library.

Comment: Of course, CRUD operations are supported. Changes to the current row are flushed when you advance to another row. It's even possible to generate DBF files from scratch. However you should be aware that xbase4j currently does not use index files in any way.